# How to optimize this query for inserting/updating millions of records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, datatable

I have 4 tables in SQL Server: `AspNetUsers`, `CustomerFile`, `CustomerOption` and `LastPullRecords`. Application uploads the customer records from an Excel file. This Excel file is converted into `DataTable` and then for each row of the `DataTable` this stored procedure is called.

There is a trigger applied on the `CustomerFile` table. In this stored procedure first we check if `FirstName`, `LastName`, `StreetAddress`, `City`, `State` and `Zip` are not changed, then update only officer details other wise update all details, set the action to update ('U') and that will send the record to third party next day. Second, if that customer is not present then add it and set the action as add ('A'). After that if available then we update two other tables based on customer records.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[InsertUpdateRecords]
(
    @FullName NVARCHAR(50) =NULL,
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(50) =NULL,
    @LastName NVARCHAR(50) =NULL,
    @StreetAddress NVARCHAR(50) =NULL,
    @City NVARCHAR(50) =NULL,
    @State NVARCHAR(50) =NULL,
    @Zip INT =NULL,
    @SSN NVARCHAR(50) =NULL,
    @Email NVARCHAR(150) =NULL,
    @OfficerEmail NVARCHAR(50) =NULL,
    @OfficerId NVARCHAR(50)=NULL,
    @OfficerName NVARCHAR(50) =NULL,
    @Option NVARCHAR(50) =NULL,
    @DownloadedFromFTP BIT =NULL,
    @LastPullDate DATETIME=NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @IsActive BIT
DECLARE @FileID INT
DECLARE @CompanyId INT

SET @IsActive=1

--Get Company ID based on OfficerID
Select @CompanyId=CompanyId from AspNetUsers where Email=@OfficerEmail

select top (1) @FileID=cf.fileId from CustomerFile cf inner join AspNetUsers usr on usr.Id=cf.OfficerId  where cf.SSN = @SSN and usr.CompanyId=@CompanyId order by cf.FileReceivedDate, cf.FileId desc

if ((@FileID<>'') or(@FileID is not null))
    Begin
        -- COMPARE IF ONLY OFFICER IS CHANGED
        If EXISTS(select 1 from CustomerFile where FirstName=@FirstName and LastName=@LastName and StreetAddress=@StreetAddress and City=@City and State=@State and Zip=@Zip
         and FileId=@FileID         
            )
            BEGIN
                UPDATE top (1) CustomerFile SET OfficerEmail=@OfficerEmail,
                OfficerName=@OfficerName,Email=@Email,
                ----FileModifiedDate=GETDATE(),
                DownloadedFromFTP=@DownloadedFromFTP,IsActive=@IsActive,OfficerId=@OfficerId
                WHERE FileId=@FileID                
            END
        Else
            BEGIN
                Update top (1) CustomerFile set FullName=@FullName, FirstName=@FirstName, LastName=@LastName, StreetAddress=@StreetAddress, City=@City,State=@State,Zip=@Zip,
                OfficerEmail=@OfficerEmail,OfficerName=@OfficerName,Email=@Email,
                --FileReceivedDate=GETDATE(),
                FileModifiedDate=GETDATE(),DownloadedFromFTP=@DownloadedFromFTP,IsActive=@IsActive,Action='U'
                where FileId=@FileID
            END
    End
Else
    BEGIN
        declare @IdentityOutput table ( ID int )

        INSERT INTO CustomerFile(FullName,FirstName,LastName,StreetAddress,City,State,Zip,SSN,OfficerEmail,OfficerId,OfficerName,
        FileReceivedDate,DownloadedFromFTP,IsActive,Action,Email
        ) 
        output inserted.FileId into @IdentityOutput
        VALUES(@FullName,@FirstName,@LastName,@StreetAddress,@City,
        @State,@Zip,@SSN,@OfficerEmail,@OfficerId,@OfficerName,
        GETDATE(),@DownloadedFromFTP,@IsActive,'A',@Email)

        select @FileID = (select ID from @IdentityOutput)
    END
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Set Option
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


if ((@Option<>'') or(@Option is not null))
Begin
    if exists(select 1 from CustomerOption where CustomerFileID=@FileID)
        Begin
            Update CustomerOption Set Option=@Option where CustomerFileID=@FileID
        End
    else
        Begin
            Insert into CustomerOption (CustomerFileID, Option) values (@FileID, @Option)
        End
End

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Insert Last Pull if exist
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

if ((@LastPullDate<>'') or(@LastPullDate is not null) or CONVERT(varchar(10),@LastPullDate,101)!='01/01/1900')

Begin

if((@FileID<>'') OR (@FileID<>0))
Begin
if exists (Select * from LastPullRecords where CustomerId=@FileID and CompanyId=@CompanyId)
bEGIN
Update LastPullRecords
set  LastPullDate=@LastPullDate,
     IsSelfPull=1,
     ModifiedDateTime=getdate()
where CustomerId=@FileID and CompanyId=@CompanyId
End

ELSE

Begin
iNSERT INTO LastPullRecords
(CompanyId,CustomerId,LastPullDate,IsSelfPull,IsRTS,CreatedDateTime)
values
(@CompanyId,@FileID,@LastPullDate,1,0,getdate())

End
End
end

END
```

Problem is that there could be thousands of records and this query will take very long time to upload all those records. For testing i uploaded only 10K records and it took 13 minutes.

I tried to send the DataTable as parameter, defining custom User Table Type for the datatable, using while loop , then cursor but all these experiments are not making any difference.

Please suggest any optimized way to upload these records so it take less time.

Comment: Actually i haven't, It was typo. let me edit this.

Comment: `and then for each row of the DataTable this stored procedure is called.` Row-by-row processing is slow, use set-based approach like (read all data from excel and process them as one batch). For more info please read [RBAR: ‘Row By Agonizing Row’](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can choose from two options, if you want to keep using .NET for this task:

- use [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) to copy data into intermediate tables (may be you can write insert without intermediate table), then write one command to insert all new data and second command to update all changed data.
- use [Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) instead of SqlBulkCopy and intermediate tables (if your MSSQL not less than 2012)

Note, that SqlBulkCopy *can* be slower than Table-Valued Parameters for small data sets, but faster for big data sets.